# socket.io not working on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

Whenever I try to use `require("socket.io");` on heroku it fails with the message "Cannot find module socket.io".

I think it’s an issue with my setup, because the same is running fine in my local node.js server.

What do I have to change?

Comment: does anyone know if/when Heroku plans on supporting websockets/real-time?

Comment: It's already supported out of the box and the answers below are outdated: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/7/7/websockets_now_ga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your PaaS provider. Heroku doesn't support websockets. Where as [nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com) is known for support websockets.

Also, you might have forgot adding `socket.io` in package.json dependency lists.

Comment: Now heroku supports websockets for Node.js apps. https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/10/8/websockets-public-beta

Answer (score 6):

Heroku on cedar does not support websockets

Anyway you can use socket.io with

```
io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
io.set("polling duration", 10);
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku

Answer (score 1):

package.json modified as

```
"dependencies": {
"async":     "0.1.18",
"ejs":       "0.4.3",
"express":   "2.4.6",
"faceplate": "0.0.4",
"socket.io": "latest"   },
```

And the serverside code is:

```
var port=process.env.PORT || 3000;
var http=require('http');
var app=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.write("server listening to port:"+port);
    res.end();
}).listen(port);
socket=require("socket.io");
io=socket.listen(app);
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
    console.log("new connection");
    socket.on("eventA",function(data){
        io.sockets.emit("eventB",data);
    }); 
});
```

Working like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the transport option on socket.IO to xhr-polling with a (10) second duration, according to [this project wiki page](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Socket.IO-and-Heroku).

Answer (score 0):

websocket transport is working on Heroku in beta state. you can enable it with `heroku labs:enable websockets -a YOUR_APP_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

> These are solutions to socket.io related problems

> I hope i will work

1. Ports in your (index.js or server.js) & (index.html and your client.js) port must be different. (refer below code)

> =============your index.js file ======================

> (port here is 8000)

```
const express = require("express")
var app = express();
const http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(app);
  
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
server.listen(port,()=>
{
    console.log("Listening at port => "+port)
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    }
});

const cors = require("cors")
app.use(cors())
```

> =============your client.js file ======================

> port here is 8080

```
const socket = io.connect('https://localhost:8080/')
```

> =============your index.html file ======================

> port here is 8080

```
 <script defer src="https://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"> 
 </script>
```

> Remember your "server.js or index.js" port should be different from "client.js" port (Rememeber this is important)

> (index.html and your client.js) port must be same

2. You should always use 'http' while working with socket.io (refer above code)
3. U may not included cors as it allows u to have more resourses , without cors heroku prevent some dependencies to not install in heroku (refer above code)
4. Try replacing "io" to "io.connect"

   const socket = io.connect('https://localhost:8080/')
5. Must write  tag at the end in the HTML
6. U may forget to add this code which is must in "socket.io"

It is required in your html file

7. delete "node_modules" and "package-lock.json"
   and write "npm i" in cmd
8. This should be in package.json 's scripts

   "start":"node index.js",

I am not talking about nodemon , use simple node over here

9. May be version is creating a problem , u can avoid it by copying all "devDependencies" to "dependencies" in "package.json" and put "*" in version like this

   "dependencies": {

   "cors": "*",

   "express": "*",

   "nodemon": "*",

   "socket.io": "*"

   },

   "devDependencies": {}